# How to dynamically assign values to class properties in Python?

Tags: python, oop, python-2.7

I'm trying to do the following:
After performing a regex group search, I'm trying to assign the results to the class properties by a specific order. the number of results from the regex search varies from 1-5 values.

```
class Classification():
    def __init__(self, Entry):
        self.Entry = Entry
        self.Section = ''
        self.Class = 'Null'
        self.Subclass = 'Null'
        self.Group = 'Null'
        self.Subgroup = 'Null'


    def ParseSymbol(self,regex):

        Properties_Pointers = [self.Section,self.Class,self.Subclass,self.Group,self.Subgroup]

        Pattern_groups = re.search(regex, self.Symbol)

        i = 0
        for group in Pattern_groups.groups():
            Properties_Pointers[i] = group
            i += 1
```

the problem is that for each loop iteration, instead of the class property, `Properties_Pointers[i]` gets the property's value (and of course in this case I can't assign the desired value to the property).

thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Refer to attribute *names* instead, and use the [`setattr()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#setattr) to store a new value on `self`:

```
def ParseSymbol(self, regex):
    attributes = ['Section', 'Class', 'Subclass', 'Group', 'Subgroup']

    Pattern_groups = re.search(regex, self.Symbol)

    for group, attr in zip(Pattern_groups.groups(), attributes):
        setattr(self, attr, group)
```

`setattr()` lets you set attributes based on a variable, here taking from `attributes`; there is also a companion [`getattr()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr) to retrieve attributes dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

[`setattr()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#setattr) will set the attributes of an object based on a string name.  You can rewrite `ParseSymbol` above:

```
    def ParseSymbol(self,regex):

        Properties_Pointers = ['Section','Class','Subclass','Group','Subgroup']

        Pattern_groups = re.search(regex, self.Symbol)

        i = 0
        for group in Pattern_groups.groups():
            setattr(self, Properties_Pointers[i], group)
            i += 1
```

As a side note, you can iterate over both `Pattern_groups.groups()` and `Pattern_Pointers` simultaneously by using [`zip()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip).  This cleans up the code by removing the index variable `i` and its incrementation:

```
        for pointer, group in zip(Properties_Pointers, Pattern_groups.groups()):
            setattr(self, pointer, group)
```

Comment: My original version did that, until I realized that there could be *fewer groups* than there are attributes.

Comment: But then again, `zip()` will terminate when the shortest list is exhausted anyway. I need more caffeine, clearly.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that your regex will always contain the same number of groups, you can just use tuple unpacking:

```
self.Section, self.Class, self.Subclass,self.Group, self.Subgroup = Pattern_groups.groups()
```

Comment: Except that the regular expression may contain fewer groups than attributes?

Comment: Yes, but in that case the original code would also assign the matching groups to the wrong attributes so I assume that all the groups will match for the expected input.

Comment: Why would it do that? If the regex has 3 groups, then only the first three attributes are assigned to.

Comment: I was talking about the case where some groups might not match, e.g. `r'(SECTION:.*?)?(CLASS:.*?)?(SUBCLASS:.*?)?'`.But if there are less actual groups in the regex than there are properties, then of course tuple unpacking won't work.

Comment: Clearly the original code did not use named groups; it was expecting to work with positional groups only. :-)

Comment: You are right, but `r'(SECTION:.*?)?(CLASS:.*?)?(SUBCLASS:.*?)?'` does not contain any named groups :). Acually I just realized that non-matching groups are returned as `None` by `groups()`, so it's really just a matter of the number of groups in the regex.

Comment: Ah, my mistake; I thought you were using a psuedo-regex syntax to name groups, but you meant to show empty groups instead. Yes, optional groups are *always* returned, even if empty.