# Dynamically adding getters / setters using lambda functions in Python classes

Tags: python, class, dynamic, properties, lambda

I want to be able to create python objects with instance attributes defined dynamically from a dictionary. I am aware of at least two ways of doing this, simply calling `setattr(self, k, v)` or alternatively calling `setattr(FooClass, k, property(lambda x: v))`. The first option works completely fine, but I can't get the second to do what I want. Consider the following code

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, d):
        for k in d:
            setattr(A, k, property(lambda x: ('Value(%s)' % d[k], 'Key(%s)' % k, d)))

>>> a = A({'foo':'1','bar':'2'})
>>> a.foo
('Value(2)', 'Key(bar)', {'bar': '2', 'foo': '1'})
```

Why does `a.foo` not return the value of `foo` in the dictionary? The `property` objects and their getters are distinct.

```
>>> A.foo, A.bar
<property at 0x1106c1d60>, <property at 0x1106c1d08>
>>> A.foo.__get__
<method-wrapper '__get__' of property object at 0x1106c1d60>
>>> A.bar.__get__
<method-wrapper '__get__' of property object at 0x1106c1d08>
```

There are quite a few related questions on SO, the best one being this ([How to add property to a class dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1325673/python-how-to-add-property-to-a-class-dynamically)) and `Eevee`'s answer. That doesn't quite explain the behaviour though.

These deal with attributes on a class instance, not `Property` objects on the Class

- [Python extremely dynamic class properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19204847/python-extremely-dynamic-class-properties)
- [How to dynamically assign values to class properties in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19153328/how-to-dynamically-assign-values-to-class-properties-in-python)

**UPDATE**

Thanks to Martijn Pieters for his help ([answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17167764/local-scope-beyond-the-scope-of-the-enclosing)). The answer lies in the scope of the lambda function.

```
>>> A.bar.fget.__closure__[0], A.foo.fget.__closure__[0]
<cell at 0x1106c63d0: dict object at 0x7f90f699fe80>, <cell at 0x1106c63d0: dict object at 0x7f90f699fe80>
```

Working version:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, d):
        for k, v in d.items():
            setattr(A, k, property(lambda x, v=v, k=k: ('Value(%s)' % v, 'Key(%s)' % k, d)))
```

Although this actually modifies every instance of the class to have the same attribute values.

Lesson:

> be careful with `lambda` functions inside loops

Comment: You are running into closures here: [Local scope, beyond the scope of the enclosing](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17167764)

Comment: Another possible duplicate: [Local variables in Python nested functions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12423614)

Comment: @MattiLyra Please dont delete it, lot of useful links.

Comment: @MartijnPieters So, what is the best way to fix this problem?

Comment: @thefourtheye: See the linked posts; bind the value as a keyword argument default (so the value is stored on the `lambda` object), or create a new scope with a separate factory function.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Got it :) I changed it to, `setattr(A, k, property(lambda x, l=l: l))` Thanks a lot :)